# Wanting to create and use custom library in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a few classes I'd like to use as general-purpose libraries, but I don't understand how I'd be able to create the library and be able to type something like "import myLib" or similar into the project sources I'm working on. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating libs is easy:
`Tools -> Libraries -> New library`

You can then import your library to any projects that use it, the same way you would do any other:
`Project properties`
OR
`Right-click libraries folder/package -> Add library / Add project`

Comment: I got stuck on NOT using the default package - old habits die hard! Thanks a ton!